# How to create data patch to insert data in dynamic blocks in Magento 2.4?

Tags: database, magento2.4.3, patch-data, data-patch, dynamic-blocks

How to create data patch to insert data into the database for dynamic blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchVersionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterfaceFactory;

class InsertDynamicBlock implements DataPatchInterface, PatchVersionInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var BlockRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $blockRepository;

    /**
     * @var BlockInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $blockFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository,
        BlockInterfaceFactory $blockFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;
        $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();

        // Insert logic to create and insert data into dynamic blocks
        $blockData = [
            'title' => 'Dynamic Block Title',
            'identifier' => 'dynamic_block_identifier',
            'content' => 'Dynamic Block Content',
            'is_active' => 1,
            'stores' => [0], // Store IDs
        ];

        $block = $this->blockFactory->create();
        $block->setData($blockData);
        $this->blockRepository->save($block);

        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public static function getVersion()
    {
        return '1.0.0';
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();

        // Revert logic if needed

        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Let me know if any quries.

**`Thanks.`**

Comment: Asking for dynamic blocks not cms block. Core Module name: module-banner

Answer (score 0):

Refer code below

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchVersionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Banner\Model\Banner\Validator;
use Magento\Banner\Model\Banner;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Class BannerDynamicBlock
 */
class BannerDynamicBlock implements DataPatchInterface, PatchVersionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    protected $bannerValidator;

    /**
     * @var Banner
     */
    private $banner;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param Validator $bannerValidator
     * @param Banner $banner
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        Validator $bannerValidator,
        Banner $banner,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->bannerValidator = $bannerValidator;
        $this->banner = $banner;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();
        $this->createDynamicBlock();
        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function createDynamicBlock()
    {
        $data = [
            'default_contents' => '',
            'use_default_value' => 'false',
            'show_use_default_value' => 'false',
            'name' => 'Test',
            'is_enabled' => '1',
            'types' => ['content'],
            'customer_sectment_ids' => [],
            'banner_sales_rules' => [],
            'store_id' => 0,
            'content_readonly' => false,
            'readonly' => false
        ];

        /** @var Banner $banner */
        $banner = $this->banner;
        $data = $this->bannerValidator->prepareSaveData($data);

      try {
            $this->prepareBannerModelData($banner, $data);
            $banner->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error('Cannot save the dynamic block, Exeption: ' . $e . '.  Please try again.');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Banner $banner
     * @param array $data
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareBannerModelData(\Magento\Banner\Model\Banner $banner, array $data)
    {
        //$content = $this->dynamicBlockContent();

        $data['store_contents'] = [
          0 => "Some content"
        ];

        $data['default_contents'] = [
          0 => "Some content"
        ];

        $banner->setData($data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getVersion()
    {
        return '1.0.0';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: I am asking dynamic block not cms block.

Comment: Core Module name: module-banner

Comment: @VinodKumar Check edited answer above.